# is it possible to make a packaged app to burn disc(CD, DVD, BD) for chrome book

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os, dvd-burning, chromebook

I`m beginner for chrome packaged app.
I want to make a app to burn DVDs, BDs, CDs on chrome os , is it possible?
I heard chrome os prevent burn disc because of patent, is it right?
Is there any method to burn disc ?

and How can I get handls for SATA device such as SDD, HDD, ODD on chrome OS?

Answer (score 0):

There is an experimental API for doing this, but it's still in the development phase.

http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/api/image_writer_private.idl

I think eventually the plan is to let 3rd party apps use it, but right now access to it is gated on a whitelist until some security issues can be ironed out.